# Eclipse AVD not displaying

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run through the hello world example for android development.  I'm at the point where i click the AVD Manager on the toolbar to choose my device.  The first time i clicked it, it came up and displayed but froze when i tried to save a device with my settings.  After that, i will click the AVD Manager button and absoultely nothing happens.
Does anyone know where i can look to see if eclipse is throwing error code or why this is occuring?  I ran it from command line with success, though it was quite slow:

C:\Android_Development\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools>android list targets

### Available Android targets:

id: 1 or "android-17"
     Name: Android 4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 17
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a

I'm running Win7 x64 Eclipse 3.8, ADT v21.0.0, java 1.6 (I believe / i can't find which one the hello world is trying to use).

I'm at a loss at why the AVD is not displaying.  I can see in the memory manager at the bottom left of eclipse that the memory used increases by 1M every time i click the button, so something is happening...

Answer (score 0):

Hi mate first check whether your system configuration supports the Emulator or not,because the higher level API needs supportable PC configuration.May be you have configuration that doesn't supported some functionality of the API level 17.Once Check running with lower level API then you may get some idea.All the Best Mate.

Comment: what system configuration are you talking about?

Comment: what is your present system configuration? is it a old system?